# Constraints that are relative to screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints, grid-layout

Is there a way to make constraints change based on the screen size of your device, like percentages in CSS? I have a grid of images that will look good on only on device. Will `CollectionViewController` fix my problem, or maybe testing for screen size and linking to a different `Storyboard` depending on the screen size?

Comment: checkout the size classes presentations from WWDC on how to handle adaptive layouts. Or take an equal widths/heights constraint to the superview and apply a multiplier for ratio

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit" http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/216xxcnxc6wnkf3/216/216_hd_building_adaptive_apps_with_uikit.mov?dl=1  Also take a look at the "Alternate Views" sample code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AlternateViews/Introduction/Intro.html The latter is probably more useful when dealing with table or collection views on different devices. Although a slightly different approach - one that I implemented successfully - is to swap in different datasources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using Storyboard constraints and programatically**

There are many approaches, this is only the approach I use:

*1) Add constraint in Storyboard*

[image]

*.*

*2) Access constraint in View Controller programatically (Drag and Drop in Assistant editor)*

[image]

*3) Change constraint value dependant on screen size*

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
imWidth.constant = screenSize.width * 0.85 // Make width 85% of Screen Width
```

Comment: How are you testing for the screen size.? How does it work?

Comment: So, `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` returns the screen dimensions. We don't care too much what these are. Only we multiply them by `x/100` where `x` is the percentage of the dimension you want your view to cover. Does this make sense?

Comment: This way, no matter what iPhone you use, the view will cover 85% of the width of the screen, in the above case. `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` returns different dimensions depending on which iPhone you are using

Comment: I decided I should use a collection view, which is what I am trying to implement now.

Comment: What files, and where in the files, should this code go?

Answer (score 1):

These 4 constraints change the objects according to screen sizes, but for that you shouldn't give any width or height constraint. Top edge,Leading edge,Trailing edge,Bottom edge. Now you can check how it will look by selecting the view and clicking Assistant Editor,then Automatic, then Preview. There will be +sign at the bottom of screen, click on that and add the devices on which you want to check.